# Extract numbers only from specific lines within a txt file with certain keywords in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to extract numbers only from lines in a txt file that have a certain keyword and add them up then compare them, and then print the highest total number and the lowest total number. How should I go about this?

I want to print the highest and the lowest valid total numbers

I managed to extract lines with "valid" keyword in them, but now I want to get numbers from this lines, and then add the numbers up of each line, and then compare these numbers with other lines that have the same keyword and print the highest and the lowest valid numbers.

**my code so far**

```
#get file object reference to the file 
file = open("shelfs.txt", "r")

#read content of file to string
data = file.read()

#close file<br>
closefile = file.close()


#get number of occurrences of the substring in the string

totalshelfs = data.count("SHELF")
totalvalid = data.count("VALID")
totalinvalid = data.count("INVALID")

print('Number of total shelfs :', totalshelfs)
print('Number of valid valid books :', totalvalid)
print('Number of invalid books :', totalinvalid)
```

**txt file**

```
HEADER|<br>
SHELF|2200019605568|<br>
BOOK|20200120000000|4810.1|20210402|VALID|<br>
SHELF|1591024987400|<br>
BOOK|20200215000000|29310.0|20210401|VALID|<br>
SHELF|1300001188124|<br>
BOOK|20200229000000|11519.0|20210401|VALID|<br>
SHELF|1300001188124|<br>
BOOK|20200329001234|115.0|20210331|INVALID|<br>
SHELF|1300001188124|<br>
BOOK|2020032904567|1144.0|20210401|INVALID|<br>
FOOTER|
```

Comment: Can you please share sample expected output.

Comment: what I am trying to get is; Highest number of valid book is 20200229000000|11519.0|20210401 and the lowest number of valid books is 20200120000000|4810.1|20210402

Comment: Hi, there are a number of actual questions attached to this post presented kind of as a "here is what I want to do". You will get much more help if you ask a specific question like: "*How can I parse a line in my file to get a name and an amount?  Here is what I tried already...."  anyways, if you want to `read()` the entire file into a variable, you might then look at `split("\n")` to break it back into lines and for each line look at `split("|")` to get the values within the line.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to use the pandas library.

https://pandas.pydata.org/

You can read a csv file like this:

```
data = pd.read_csv('shelfs.txt', sep='|')
```

it returns a DataFrame object that can easily select or sort your data. It will use the first row as header, then you can select a specific column like a dictionnary:

```
header = data['HEADER']
```

header is a Series object.

To select columns you can do:

```
shelfs = data.loc[:,data['HEADER']=='SHELF']
```

to select only the row where the header is 'SHELF'.

I'm just not sure how pandas will handle the fact that you only have 1 header but 2 or 5 columns.

Maybe you should try to create one header per colmun in your csv, and add separators to make each row the same size first.

Edit (No External libraries or change in the txt file):

```
# Split by row
data = data.split('<br>\n')

# Split by col
data = [d.split('|') for d in data]

# Fill empty cells
n_cols = max([len(d) for d in data])
for i in range(len(data)):
    while len(data[i])<n_cols:
        data[i].append('')

# List VALID rows
valid_rows = [d for d in data if d[4]=='VALID']

# Get sum min and max
valid_sum = [d[1]+d[2]+d[3] for d in valid_rows]
valid_minimum = min(valid_sum)
valid_maximum = max(valid_sum)
```

It's maybe not exactly what you want to do but it solves a part of your problem. I didn't test the code.

Comment: I cannot use external libraries or change the txt file